# Sum-coloring a tournament

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, directed-graphs

If $G=(V,E)$ is a loopless finite directed graph and $v\in V$, we set $\text{In}(v) = \{(w,v): w\in V \land (w,v) \in E\}$.

Let $T=(V,E)$ be a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) such that for every  $v\in V$ the set $\text{In}(v)$ contains at least $2$ elements. Is there a map $c: V\to \mathbb{Z}$ with the following properties?

1. for all $v\in V$ we have $c(v) = \sum_{w\in \text{In}(v)} c(w)$, and
2. $c$ is not the constant $0$-map.

Comment: In other words, you are asking whether $1$ is always an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of $T$. (Because the $c$ you are looking for is a nonzero eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: The answer is "no", since the matrix $\left( \begin{array} [c]{ccccc} 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)  $ is the adjacency matrix of a $5$-vertex tournament with all indegrees $= 2$, but its characteristic polynomial: $X^{5}-5X^{2}-5X-2=\left( X-2\right)  \left(  3X+4X^{2}+2X^{3}+X^{4}+1\right)  $ does not have $1$ as a root.

Comment: Great - can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. For a counterexample, let $T$ be the tournament with vertex
set $V=\left\{  1,2,3,4,5\right\}  $ and arc set
\begin{align*}
E  & =\left\{  \left(  1,2\right)  ,\left(  1,3\right)  ,\left(  2,3\right)
,\left(  2,4\right)  ,\left(  3,4\right)  ,\left(  3,5\right)  ,\left(
4,5\right)  ,\left(  4,1\right)  ,\left(  5,1\right)  ,\left(  5,2\right)
\right\}  \\
& =\left\{  \left(  i,i+1\right)  \ \mid\ 1\leq i\leq5\right\}  \cup\left\{
\left(  i,i+2\right)  \ \mid\ 1\leq i\leq5\right\}
\end{align*}
(where indices are modulo $5$). Each veretx of $T$ has indegree $2$ and
outdegree $2$. Your map $c$ must thus satisfy the following system of linear
equations:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
c\left(  1\right)  =c\left(  4\right)  +c\left(  5\right)  ;\\
c\left(  2\right)  =c\left(  5\right)  +c\left(  1\right)  ;\\
c\left(  3\right)  =c\left(  1\right)  +c\left(  2\right)  ;\\
c\left(  4\right)  =c\left(  2\right)  +c\left(  3\right)  ;\\
c\left(  5\right)  =c\left(  3\right)  +c\left(  4\right)
\end{array}
\right.  .
\end{equation}
But the only solution to this system is when all $c\left(  v\right)  $ are $0$.